# How do you override fields in Scala?

Tags: scala, overriding, visibility, member

For instance, buf is protected variable in BAOS. I would like to make it public. Currently, I resort to duplicate name

```
    class Baos extends ByteArrayOutputStream {
        def getbuf = buf // expose the buffer
    }
```

Can I change the visibility without inventing another name, like I override the methods?

Comment: I think this is not possible. What's wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buf` is a protected variable:

```
   26   package java.io;
   ...
   45   public class ByteArrayOutputStream extends OutputStream {
   46   
   47       /**
   48        * The buffer where data is stored.
   49        */
   50       protected byte buf[];
```

So the only 2 ways to access it are:

- exposing it like you did or
- accessing it from a class within the `java.io` package

I don't see any way to "change the visibility". However I would ask myself why I want to make that internal variable publicly accessible risking to have [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) issues.

> Protected variables generally have some intrinsic invariance
>   associated with them (or else they'd be public). Inheritors then need
>   to maintain those properties, which people can screw up or willfully
>   violate.

The base class probably is making many assumptions about `buf` not being accessed externally to don't violate the [Open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

I would rather focus on "favour composition over inheritance".